# Compiling multiple Objective-C files on the command line with clang

Tags: objective-c, c, clang

Hopefully simple question. I'm trying to learn basic Objective-C compiling from the command line, with clang. I understand that Xcode is a better solution for complex projects and I plan on moving to it soon, but I personally feel I understand a language better if I can compile it manually in a terminal, and for small introductory programming projects I find it less of a hassle to compile in a terminal than having to start a new project.

So the question is: how do I compile an Objective-C program that consists of multiple files (from the command line)? (I'm trying to do the fraction program from chapter 7 of Kochan's textbook, with a main.m and Fraction.m file that both #import "Fraction.h", and a Fraction.h file that imports the Foundation framework.) To compile a single file I use something like

```
clang -fobjc-arc main.m -o prog1
```

But if I type that and I want to include files other than main.m in the project, I get errors including:

```
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

If I try to add the additional files to the command as arguments, like

```
clang -fobjc-arc main.m Fraction.h Fraction.m -o prog1
```

then I get

```
clang: error: cannot specify -o when generating multiple output files
```

And if I then remove the -o argument like

```
clang -fobjc-arc main.m Fraction.h Fraction.m
```

then I get a giant pile of errors all referring to the foundation framework, eventually ending in "fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now".

How do I do this and make it work? Or do I need to just suck it up and use Xcode as soon as more than one file is involved?

Comment: One error is that you specify the include file "Fraction.h" as argument to the compiler.

Comment: Ah! Thanks. That's it: it needed to be just the .m files and not the .h.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Only the implementation files (*.m) are compiled, not the interface/include files, so this should work:

```
clang -fobjc-arc main.m Fraction.m -o prog1
```

The strange error message "generating multiple output files" is probably caused by the fact
that clang can also  compile header files to "precompiled header files".

Comment: -fobjc-arc is not supported on platforms using the legacy runtime

Comment: @AbdennourTOUMI: That is correct. But *this* question was apparently about how to compile Objective-C code *with ARC* on the command line. Otherwise just omit that option.

Comment: no ,,no , , i mean this is an error which is displayed when i am trying to compile those files https://github.com/macmade/host-manager/tree/master/source under Ubuntu ... I will be thankful if you explain to me how to compile those files under LINUX

Comment: @AbdennourTOUMI: At present, I do not have a Linux computer with Clang and Objective-C, so I cannot help you with that.

Answer (score 2):

Don't specify `Fraction.h` as a source file. It's not, it's a header file.

You also almost certainly want to throw in `-framework Foundation`. If you use any other frameworks you'll probably need to specify these as well.